# Como faço para para printar de Lado usando end=" " com o Módulo Time incluido

Tags: python-3.x, string, concatenação-de-string

```
import time
for i in range(0,10,+1):
    print(".", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Quero saber como faço para printar os `.` de lado `ex: ...` 
Durante esse tempo de 1 segundo... quando não uso o `end` ele funciona mas
printando para baixo.

Comment: Pelo teste que fiz está a funcionar normalmente, imprimindo lado a lado, segundo a segundo.

Comment: Pode variar de acordo com as características do terminal - no idle de um jeito, jupyter de outro, cmd do windows de outro, terminal de Unix de outro - em terminais Unix é necessário o `flush`, como indiquei na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Para continuar a impressão na mesma linha a medida que ela acontece,
além de mudar o caractere de final de linha com o parâmetro `end`, é necessário passar também o parâmetro `flush=True` para sincronizar o arquivo sem que o final de linha esteja presente:

```
import time
for i in range(0,10,+1):
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```